# WebApi fails to start when run as service

Tags: c#, .net-core, raspberry-pi3, asp.net-core-webapi, raspbian

I am having a weired problem.

Running my web-api like this works:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/dotnet /usr/local/bin/dotnetcoreapps/api/TestService.dll
```

I've created this test-service.service in `/etc/systemd/system/`:

```
[Unit]
Description=DoorplateBackendService
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=pi
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/dotnet /usr/local/bin/dotnetcoreapps/api/TestService.dll
KillSignal=SIGINT    

[Install]
WantedBy=network-online.target
```

Somehow I get this exception, I have no idea where it comes from:

```
System.IO.IOException: Invalid argument
at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1.FindNextEntry()
at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.RunningInstance.AddDirectoryWatchUnlocked(WatchedDirectory parent, String directoryName)
at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.RunningInstance.AddDirectoryWatchUnlocked(WatchedDirectory parent, String directoryName)
at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.RunningInstance.AddDirectoryWatchUnlocked(WatchedDirectory parent, String directoryName)
at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.RunningInstance.AddDirectoryWatchUnlocked(WatchedDirectory parent, String directoryName)
at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.RunningInstance.AddDirectoryWatchUnlocked(WatchedDirectory parent, String directoryName)
at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.RunningInstance.AddDirectoryWatchUnlocked(WatchedDirectory parent, String directoryName)
at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.RunningInstance..ctor(FileSystemWatcher watcher, SafeFileHandle inotifyHandle, String directoryPath, Boolean includeSubdirectories, NotifyFilters notifyFilters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEvents()
at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEventsIfNotDisposed()
at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.set_EnableRaisingEvents(Boolean value)
at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.PhysicalFilesWatcher.TryEnableFileSystemWatcher()
at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.PhysicalFilesWatcher.CreateFileChangeToken(String filter)
at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider.Watch(String filter)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.<.ctor>b__0_0()
at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.OnChange(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action changeTokenConsumer)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider..ctor(FileConfigurationSource source)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationSource.Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.BuildCommonServices(AggregateException& hostingStartupErrors)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
at BrodicatorService.Program.Main(String[] args) in <my_dir>\Program.cs:line 23;
```

Program.cs - Line23: `CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();`

Comment: Please add code how method `CreateWebHostBuilder` looks

Comment: @IgorCova I could add it but since it works when run from terminal I don't think there is any issue. I don't want to flood this question with code.

Comment: Okay :) I would also advise you to run .net Core app in the Docker container. It'is very convenient and flexible

Comment: The stack trace points to FileSystemWatcher, which is used to monitor configuration files changes. I encountered this issue in an ASP.NET Core 5 app running in a Docker container. The author of the Dockerfile made a mistake and published the application right in the root of the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of debugging and trying different stuff I ended up changing my service definition:

```
[Unit]
Description=MyTestService

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/usr/local/bin/dotnetcoreapps/api
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/dotnet /usr/local/bin/dotnetcoreapps/api/TestService.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
User=root
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've found [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-2.2) which helped a lot.

I don't know what happened here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my .NET 5 project, and tried experimenting with the ".service" file.

The solution to me, was to change the working directory to "/tmp". I think it workes because my application is located on a mounted network disk (NFS).

The MS Demo server-side project worked, without the working directory set to "/tmp".

Btw, I do not have ernogh point to comment, so I post a answer instead.